# How often should I upgrade Debian testing?

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, updates

How often do you guys upgrade your Debian testing installation?
Is it better to do it at short (i.e. every day) or long (i.e. every other week) intervals? Why?

Comment: Questions that ask for opinions are not a good fit for Superuser. Check out the FAQ http://superuser.com/faq

Comment: OMG. You should always apply all security fixes immediately. Why would you leave a security vulnerability in your system???

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely up to you, but there are some things you should consider.

- Debian testing is more likely to have major or security bugs fixed by an update (for being testing obviously)
- Daily updating makes the download trivial, every-other-week updating could be cumbersome specially on slowish internet connections.
- If you do report bugs, then daily updating is a must.

Comment: downvoted? whatever